# Get only footer css from materialize

Tags: css, download, materialize

I have a webpage with my own css and bootstrap v4, but I want to use the footer of Materialize, but I don't want to use the entire css code to avoid conflicts with bootstrap, is there any way to get only this part of css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if there exist some other code for this . you can try mdbootstrap or similar . but here is a snippet that i have made .

html

```
<!--Footer-->
<footer class="page-footer blue center-on-small-only">
  <!--Footer Links-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!--First column-->
      <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
        <h3 class="title">Footer Content</h3>
        <p>Here you can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
      </div>
      <!--/.First column-->
      <hr class="hidden-md-up">
      <!--Second column-->
      <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
        <h5 class="title">Links</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.Second column-->
      <hr class="hidden-md-up">
      <!--Third column-->
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h5 class="title">Links</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.Third column-->
      <hr class="hidden-md-up">
      <!--Fourth column-->
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h5 class="title">Links</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.Fourth column-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Footer Links-->
  <!--Copyright-->
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      © 2017 Copyright: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/4004879/jayakrishnan">jayakrishnancn.co.nf </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.Copyright-->
</footer>
<!--/.Footer-->
```

css

```
.blue {
  background: #ee6e73;
}

.page-footer {
  color: #fff;
}
.page-footer .title {
  line-height: 2em;
}
.page-footer .container-fluid {
  padding: 10px;
}
.page-footer li, .page-footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.page-footer a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page-footer .footer-copyright {
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.08);
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```